# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'identify'

Tags: pyqgis-3, attributeerror

I'm trying to run a console script, but it gives an error:
:

> AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'identify'

Yet it works well in QGIS 3.7

Here is the script:

```
import sys
import time
import os
import PyQt5
import numpy

# Qgis modules
from osgeo import gdal
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

#from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis import *
from PyQt5 import *
from qgis.core import QgsRasterDataProvider

chemin = 'D:/Projet_Python_Soil/tests/'

for element in os.listdir(chemin):
    if element.endswith('.tif'):
        fileInfo = QFileInfo(element)
        baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(chemin + element, baseName)
        print (baseName)
        ident = rlayer.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(368371, -406601), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
        #os.system("pause")
        print (ident.results())
        if ident.isValid():
            iden = {}
            iden = ident.results()
            print (iden[1])
```

Comment: change your path to `chemin = r'D:\Projet_Python_Soil\tests'` , but you have a error in the identify method too

Comment: I'm trying to run this console script, but it gets me wrong:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no 'identify' attribute

yet it works well in Qgis3.7

here is the script the question:

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code for work. You need put the correct path (Look mine),[identify](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterDataProvider.html#a5b033a4ab93593c8378af8005ed52ccd) method need a `QgsPointXY`object and make a correct source for create `QgsRasterLayer` object

**Note** : For this snippet you don't need all these imports

Code:

```
import sys
import time
import os
import PyQt5
import numpy

# Qgis modules
from osgeo import gdal
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

#from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis import *
from PyQt5 import *
from qgis.core import QgsRasterDataProvider

chemin = r'C:\Users\fran\Downloads\qgis_sample_data\qgis_sample_data\raster'

for element in os.listdir(chemin):
    if element.endswith('.tif'):
        fileInfo = QFileInfo(element)
        baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(chemin+ "\\" + element, baseName)
        print (baseName)
        ident = rlayer.dataProvider().identify(QgsPointXY(48256,3536957), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
        if ident.isValid():
            iden = {}
            iden = ident.results()
            print (iden[1])
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this console script, but it gets me wrong:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no 'identify' attribute

yet it works well in Qgis3.7

here is the script the question:

Comment: What qgis version are you using?

Comment: la version qgis3.6